# How to attach a file to the email notification in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, email-notifications

I would like to know is it possible to edit the template of the email notifications in TeamCity for sending some files attached to the email message? Can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to use `jmeter-ant-task` to solve this. The `teamcity` run the `ant` script which launches the `jmeter` tests and in the final step of this test it sends the email with the test result attachments and logs. For the team city I didn't find any native solution to send email attachments.

Comment: Dear Shurupus, could you, please, share your experience in integration JMeter and TeamCity? It's interesting, how did you solve step-by-step JMeter's performance script automation in TeamCity?

Comment: @NadezhdaT, hi, I believe, it's a big work to describe it here. Could you email me? My nickname on stackoverflow gmail com